# Java OpenCV Video capture cut off

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture, opencv3.0

i am Brand new to OpenCV in java been trying to create an image capture program which both records the user and allows images to be moved to the captured image area on the GUI, my only issue is the recording seems to be cut off even when I specified a region for where it should be displayed, any help will be highly appricated.

```
package gesture.recognition;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.Component;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
import static org.opencv.videoio.Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT;
import static org.opencv.videoio.Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH;

public class GestureRecognition extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private DaemonThread myThread = null;
    int count = 0;
    VideoCapture webSource = null;
    Mat vid = new Mat();
    MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();
    int CANVAS_INITIAL_WIDTH =400;
    int CANVAS_INITIAL_HEIGHT =500;
    int Video_display=400;
    int Button_Area=200;
    float h,s,v;
    int alpha,r,g,b;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    File f = null;
    Mat hsv = new Mat();

    class Canvas extends JPanel
    {
        // Called every time there is a change in the canvas contents.
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);        
            draw(g);


        }
    } 

    class DaemonThread implements Runnable
    {
    protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

    @Override
    public  void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(runnable)
            {
                if(webSource.grab())
                {
                try
                        {
                            webSource.retrieve(vid);
                            Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", vid, mem);
                Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));

                BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                Graphics g=freehandSliderPanel.getGraphics();
                            if (g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, null));
//              if (g.drawImage(buff,0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() -150 , 0 , 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(),null))



                if(runnable == false)
                            {
                    System.out.println("Going to wait()");
                    this.wait();
                }
             }
             catch(IOException | InterruptedException ex)
                         {
                System.out.println("Error");
                         }
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }

        private Canvas canvas;
        private JPanel controlPanel;
        private JPanel messageArea;
        private JButton jButton1;
        private JPanel freehandSliderPanel;

        public GestureRecognition() 
    {
        setTitle("Gesture Recognition");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());  // Layout manager for the frame.

        // Canvas
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Video"));
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_INITIAL_WIDTH, CANVAS_INITIAL_HEIGHT));
        add(canvas, BorderLayout.WEST);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
          controlPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Picture"));
          controlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Video_display, CANVAS_INITIAL_HEIGHT));
          // the following two lines put the control panel in a scroll pane (nicer?).      
          JScrollPane controlPanelScrollPane = new JScrollPane(controlPanel);
          controlPanelScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Video_display + 30, CANVAS_INITIAL_HEIGHT));
        add(controlPanelScrollPane, BorderLayout.EAST);

        messageArea = new JPanel();
        messageArea.setBackground(canvas.getBackground());
        messageArea.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Message Area"));
        messageArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Video_display + CANVAS_INITIAL_WIDTH, Button_Area));
        add(messageArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jButton1 = new JButton("Start Video");
          jButton1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Button_Area - 10, 50));
        messageArea.add(jButton1);



        freehandSliderPanel = new JPanel();
          freehandSliderPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_INITIAL_WIDTH - 20, 90));
          canvas.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
          freehandSliderPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Display"));
        canvas.add(freehandSliderPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);




        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        jButton1.setText("Video Capture");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
    }


        void draw(Graphics g)
    {

    }// end draw method 



   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    webSource =new VideoCapture(0);
    myThread = new DaemonThread();
            Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            myThread.runnable = true;
            t.start();
             jButton1.setEnabled(false);  //start button
//            jButton2.setEnabled(true);  // stop button
    }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        GestureRecognition GestureRecognitionInstance = new GestureRecognition();

        /*Create and display the form */
/*        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            }
        });
*/    }

}
```

So far it displays the GUI but as you can see it simply cuts off the image like so

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7TkU.png)

Comment: maybe because of JavaFX? have you tried to save the image? still the same?

Comment: When I save the image on my pc it comes out fine it's only on the jpanel that it's gets cut off

Comment: This means it's because of you GUI/JavaFX code. Try to resize both the image and the pane/container to the same size

Comment: i tried setting them both to the same size in the drawimage but it still cuts out for some strange reason

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked five years ago, but I noticed it hasn't been addressed, and I believe this may still be helpful to anyone coming across this issue.

I've made a small modification to your **jButton1ActionPerformed** method to achieve what you want. In the jButton1ActionPerformed method, I set these dimensions using the **set** method on the VideoCapture object.

```
public class GestureRecognition extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                                     
        webSource =new VideoCapture(0);
        webSource.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CANVAS_INITIAL_WIDTH);
        webSource.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CANVAS_INITIAL_HEIGHT);
        myThread = new DaemonThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        myThread.runnable = true;
        t.start();
        jButton1.setEnabled(false);  //start button
        jButton2.setEnabled(true);  // stop button
    }

    // Rest of the code
}
```